# Is editing build.prop enough to change model name?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android, stock-rom

I am trying to change the model name on my Android device by editing `build.prop`.

**Code:**

`ro.product.model=Nexus S`

**My code:**

`ro.product.model=Nexus One`

Settings still shows `Nexus S`.

Edit: I edited the fields @GokulNC suggested, but screen still shows `Nexus S`.

can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also try changing `ro.product.name` , `ro.build.product` and `ro.product.device` and reboot to see changes.. Make sure to backup your original build.prop before doing this..

Comment: @GokulNC I tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I was using a homemade device and was not editing as root.

I also had to completely shut the device down, then turn it on.